# Deleting DataFrame column in Pandas based on value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe something like this:

```
    Col0    Col1    Col2    Col3
1   a       b       g       a
2   a       d       z       a
3   a       g       x       a
4   a       h       p       a
5   a       b       c       a
```

I need to remove the columns where the value is 'a'. No other cells contain the value 'a'(Ex. Here Col1 and Col2 will have no cells with value 'a').I have around 1000 columns and I'm not really sure what all columns have the value 'a'.
The dataframe required should be something like this.,

```
    Col1    Col2
1   b       g   
2   d       z    
3   g       x    
4   h       p    
5   b       c
```

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) if need check if at least one `True` or [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) if need check all `True`s with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and `loc`, because filter columns:

```
print (df)
  Col0 Col1 Col2 Col3
0    a    a    g    a
1    a    d    z    a
2    a    g    x    a
3    a    h    p    a
4    a    b    c    a


df2 = df.loc[:, ~(df == 'a').any()]
print (df2)
  Col2
0    g
1    z
2    x
3    p
4    c

df1 = df.loc[:, ~(df == 'a').all()]
print (df1)
  Col1 Col2
0    a    g
1    d    z
2    g    x
3    h    p
4    b    c
```

Detail:

```
print (df == 'a')

   Col0   Col1   Col2  Col3
0  True   True  False  True
1  True  False  False  True
2  True  False  False  True
3  True  False  False  True
4  True  False  False  True
```

---

```
df2 = df.loc[:, (df != 'a').any()]
print (df2)
  Col1 Col2
0    a    g
1    d    z
2    g    x
3    h    p
4    b    c

df1 = df.loc[:, (df != 'a').all()]
print (df1)
  Col2
0    g
1    z
2    x
3    p
4    c

print (df != 'a')

    Col0   Col1  Col2   Col3
0  False  False  True  False
1  False   True  True  False
2  False   True  True  False
3  False   True  True  False
4  False   True  True  False
```

EDIT:

For check mixed types - numeric with strings are 2 possible solutions convert all to `string`s or compare numpy arrays:

```
df.astype(str) == 'a'
```

Or:

```
df.values == 'a'
```

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1**
Using `pd.DataFrame.dropna` with `pd.DataFrame.mask`
The concept is that I replace `'a'` with `np.nan` and then conveniently use `dropna`.

This drops the column even it has one `a`.

```
df.mask(df.astype(str).eq('a')).dropna(1)

  Col1 Col2
1    b    g
2    d    z
3    g    x
4    h    p
5    b    c
```

---

This requires that all elements of the column be `a`

```
df.mask(df.astype(str).eq('a')).dropna(1, how='all')

  Col1 Col2
1    b    g
2    d    z
3    g    x
4    h    p
5    b    c
```

---

**Option 2**
Creative way using `np.where` to find the unique column positions that have `'a'`
This is cool because `np.where` will return a tuple of arrays that give the positions of all `True` values in an array.  The second array of the tuple will be all the column positions.  I grab a unique set of those and find the other column names.

```
df[df.columns.difference(
       df.columns[np.unique(np.where(df.astype(str).eq('a'))[1]
)])]

  Col1 Col2
1    b    g
2    d    z
3    g    x
4    h    p
5    b    c
```

Or similarly with `pd.DataFrame.drop`

```
df.drop(df.columns[np.unique(np.where(df.astype(str).eq('a'))[1])], 1)

  Col1 Col2
1    b    g
2    d    z
3    g    x
4    h    p
5    b    c
```

---

**Option 3**
Probably bad way of doing it.

```
df.loc[:, ~df.astype(str).sum().str.contains('a')]

  Col1 Col2
1    b    g
2    d    z
3    g    x
4    h    p
5    b    c
```

Comment: I'd recommend `how=all` too, or else, if Col1/2 contains even one 'a', it'll be dropped too.

Comment: I think OP wants to drop if even a single `a` is in the column?  Did I read that wrong?

Comment: Oh yeah? I must’ve misunderstood then. Apologies!

Comment: It's definitely confusing.  I put both.

Comment: I tried both the options, I'm getting "Could not compare [%s] with block values" error. I'm guessing it's because my dataframe has both numerical and string data, is there a workaround for this?

Comment: @PrashanthPalaniswamy I'll fix that.  That means you have both mixed types in your dataframe.  Place a `astype(str)` after the `df`.